# Python 3: convert a ascii char to unicode escaped

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, parsing, unicode

I need to convert a ascii char to unicode escaped

Example:
`"&"`
to
`"\\u0026"`

Context:

I receive in my input two values, first is a string and another is a raw byte with some contents.
after this, the first string is used in the regex to catch data in raw.

`teste = "teste's teste & teste"
raw = '.... teste\'s teste \\u0026 teste",null,["here","here2"] ....'`

after this, regex is used with first var `teste` to get words `here` and `here2` in var `raw`, but in the case when some chars like & have in the first var, he can't find in raw any pattern because in raw the var is in unicode escape.

so i try to convert some chars like `&` to unicode escape without success

Comment: What HTML entities? Your string has no HTML entities in it.

Comment: sorry if i not be clear with this question, but the issue is only convert & to unicode escape, because the & have in html enties table, i write this, but if you don't like the title, you could help me with one better title for this?

Comment: @ahogen , ok, i really search about this all day, maybe i'm really noob, but if you find, you could share please?

Comment: "&" is already in ASCII; encoding with `unicode-escape` will have no effect.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams i need this to search with regex  in another text in which he is escaped :\

Comment: Are you using JSON?  That's usually where escapes like `\u0026` are generated.  Your raw data looks like it is from a JSON file.  The `json` module can help.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks, I'll temporally solve this with:

```
def escape_word(word):
    whitelist = [" ", "'"] + list(string.ascii_letters)
    new_word = ""
    for _c in word:
        if _c in whitelist:
            new_word += _c
        else:
            new_word += "\\u%04x" % ord(_c)
    return new_word
```

until I find a better solution.